# Android show "new" image only the first time

Tags: android

I have deployed my app and it's in use. Every month or so I update it and add new features.  I would like to show "new" image only the first time when the updated app is used by the user. How can I show it just once ? Where should I start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this may help to solve your problem:

```
public class mActivity extends Activity {
  @Overrride
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.setContentView(R.id.layout);

      // Get current version of the app
      PackageInfo packageInfo = this.getPackageManager()
          .getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
      int version = packageInfo.versionCode;

      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
      boolean shown = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("shown_" + version, false);

      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.newFeature);
      if(!shown) {
          imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          // "New feature" has been shown, then store the value in preferences
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
          editor.put("shown_" + version, true);
          editor.commit();
      } else
          imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
```

The next time you run the application, the image will not show.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server available to store the image, put it up there and download it on update.

The easy way would be to used a sharedprefernece to hold the current app version, then perform a check against that whenever it opens.  If It returns that the version is different than stored, thrn run your image downloader and display it in the way needed. :)

heres an example i use in one of my apps, place the ImageView declarations in your oncreate and give the methods thier own spots somewhere in there, and your good :)

one other thing to remember is that you can use image hosters to, like imgur, to host you "app updated" images for your customers, and since youll be updating periodically, you dont have to worry about the image being removed while its still in use (If you keep the app updated that is)

```
    private final static String URL = "http://hookupcellular.com/wp-content/images/android-app-update.png";

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadImage(URL));


private Bitmap downloadImage(String IMG_URL)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;        
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(IMG_URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
       in.close();
 } catch (IOException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
 }
 return bitmap;                
 }

private static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString); 
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect(); 

        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
        }                     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting to " + URL);
    }
    return in;     
}
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Good thought. How can do it programatically in app ? I don't have access to server as of now.